# bizarre long pause java young gc

Tags: java, linux, garbage-collection, strace

I got a very long pause time java young gc:

> 2016-11-21T15:03:09.839+0800: 15100.062: [GC (Allocation Failure)
>
> 2016-11-21T15:03:09.839+0800: 15100.062: [ParNew Desired survivor size
> 402653184 bytes, new threshold 6 (max 6)
>
> - age   1:   45038808 bytes,   45038808 total
> - age   2:    1077040 bytes,   46115848 total
> - age   3:  110144952 bytes,  156260800 total
> - age   4:  102297104 bytes,  258557904 total
> - age   5:   12136904 bytes,  270694808 total
> - age   6:       7312 bytes,  270702120 total : 5151460K->342421K(5505024K), 4.1780572 secs]
>
> 6631391K->1822507K(11796480K), 4.1786414 secs] [Times: user=2.61
> sys=0.01, **real=4.18 secs**]

And I did a strace:
[image]
It seems many processes had been suspended for 3-4 seconds, maybe java gc thread also suffered from that. Can anyone tell me how to interpret the log printed by strace. I'm a beginner to strace. Thanks a lot.
Since I didn't find an entry to upload the entire strace log, if you need it, I can mail it to you. Really appreciate it.

Comment: java uses futexes for a lot of things, it's hard to tell what that one is from strace alone. for starters you could add [safepoint statistics](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19201753/1362755) to your GC logging and also monintor your system's IO load and swap activity. and OS and jvm version might be helpful too

Comment: @the8472 Thanks very much for your answer. Maybe strace is a little coarse for the investigation. I've googled for hours and I find the perf command maybe a better choice.