# If weakly reachable objects are GC'ed then why there is OOM error

Tags: java, memory-management, memory-leaks

My understanding is that a weakly reachable object is garbage collected at the next GC cycle, if that is true then I should never get OutOfMemoryError for below code, but I get OOM error after running for 10-15 minutes.

```
    List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
    while (true) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++){
            list.add(new WeakReference<Object>(Calendar.getInstance()));
        }
    }
```

Can someone please explain why I still get OOM, I understand that size of the list will keep on increasing but my point here is that Calender objects I am creating using `Calendar.getInstance()` will be GC'ed after every `1000000` iteration so if I am not getting OOM error in `1000000` iteration then I should not get it for any subsequent loops because all previous Calender objects would have GC'ed in next loop?

Comment: The GC will not interrupt a running method.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle Where did I say that GC is interrupting a running method?

Comment: Your code and your statement together...

Comment: @TimothyTruckle - I don't understand what you are trying to say, but the GC can and will interrupt a running method; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19201332/java-gc-safepoint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ArrayList` class uses a simple strategy for managing space.  When the list's backing array is full and you add another element, the `ArrayList` allocates a larger array and copies the elements from the old one to the new one.  The new array's size will be 50% larger than the old one, up to the architectural limit on an array's size.  The following is the Java 8 implementation:

```
     private void grow(int minCapacity) {
         // overflow-conscious code
         int oldCapacity = elementData.length;
         int newCapacity = oldCapacity + (oldCapacity >> 1);
         if (newCapacity - minCapacity < 0)
             newCapacity = minCapacity;
         if (newCapacity - MAX_ARRAY_SIZE > 0)
             newCapacity = hugeCapacity(minCapacity);
         // minCapacity is usually close to size, so this is a win:
         elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, newCapacity);
     }
```

In your example, you are repeatedly adding elements to the list, which is causing the backing array for the list to grow, and grow, and grow.

Next, a `Reference` is class with 4 fields (in Java 8), one of which is the `referenent` ... which points to the object that is the target of the `Reference`.  When a `Reference` is broken, what happens is that the `referent` is set to `null`, thereby allowing the target object to be GC'd (typically in the next GC cycle ... but not necessarily).  But the `Reference` object itself is NOT freed ... unless you make it unreachable.

In your example, you are not doing anything to make the `WeakReference` objects unreachable.  Instead, they are building up in the list.

Eventually, the memory consumed by the list and the (broken) `WeakReference` objects that it holds will fill the heap, and you get an OOME.   (It will probably happen in a `Arrays.copyOf` call ... but could also happen when you are allocating a `WeakReference` or a `Calendar`)

---

If you want your list to actually release space in response to memory pressure, then you will need to detect and remove the broken `WeakReference` objects from the list.  This is not trivial.

- You *could* enqueue each `WeakReference` with in a `ReferenceQueue`, and have the queue processor remove each `WeakReference` as it is broken.  However, this would be inefficient since list removal is O(N).
- Another idea would be to have the queue processor increment a private counter, and have the `add` method use the counter to decide when it should scan and remove broken references.
- You should also consider calling `ArrayList::trimToSize` ... or equivalent ... to reduce the backing store size.  But bear in mind that that temporarily increases memory utilization.

This probably requires a custom `List` implementation.