# Java Method execution time and GC times

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection

Let's say I have a methodA which takes X ms in execution. And let's say application GC takes Y ms. Ideally my overall method time should be bound between [X,X+Y]. But in real life we are seeing the execution time to be way more than X+Y.

What other activities in JVM can contribute to this? We have looked at [safepointing time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19201753/3892213), but did not find it to be a major contributor.
What are the tools using which this additional time taken can be measured?

Comment: How do you conclude that the method execution should take X ms? Are you assuming interpreted execution, C1 compiled execution or C2 compiled execution?

Comment: so, let's say GC is happening every 60secs, I am considering non GC execution time as X

Comment: That does not answer the question, not even remotely.

Comment: in our tests jvm is running in server mode and we are hitting only 1 code path, so i assume it would be c2 compiled.

Comment: When you are benchmarking, you should have multiple runs, getting an interval, rather than a single execution time. Then, if you have a recent JVM, do a run with sufficient RAM and [GC turned off](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/post/epsilon-the-jdks-do-nothing-garbage-collector) to rule out GC effects. Then, you can compare the results…

Comment: yes, X can not be a single number but can be better described as a range of values. I am considering the mean as X. lets say gc is happening every 60 sec and Gc duration is 20ms. We are considering 55 sec's avg duration as X here( basically ignoring the 5 sec values around GC)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240195/discussion-between-best-wishes-and-holger).